# Why do Worksheet cells show "Text" error even when the code includes cDbl

Tags: excel, vba, text

Please can someone explain why cells in my worksheet are suddenly showing "Text Value" error messages when my code indicates that a value from the corresponding textbox should be `CDbl`.

This has only happened after an update at the weekend and is affecting multiple files.

```vb
Private Sub cmdAddRecord_Click()
'Used to add new transation records to the database
    Dim r As Long, sCredit As String, sDebit As String
    
    sDebit = Me.txtTransactionAmountDebit
    sCredit = Me.txtTransactionAmountCredit
    
    With Sheets("Spending Account")
        r = 1 + .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        .Cells(r, "A").Value = DTPicker1
        .Cells(r, "B").Value = cboVendorDetails
        .Cells(r, "C").Value = cboTransactionType
        .Cells(r, "F").Value = cboTransactionStatus
     
        ' credit or debit
        If Len(sDebit) > 0 Then
            If Len(sCredit) > 0 Then
                MsgBox "Warning - Both Credit and Debit", vbExclamation
            Else
                .Cells(r, "D").Value = CDbl(sDebit)
            End If
        ElseIf Len(sCredit) > 0 Then
           .Cells(r, "E").Value = CDbl(sCredit)
        End If
          
        If r > 21 Then
            Application.Goto Reference:=.Cells(r - 20, "A"), Scroll:=True
        End If
    End With

    'Unload Me
    'frmRegularTransactions.Show
    
    Call UserForm_Initialize
End Sub
```

Comment: What do `sDebit` or `sCredit` show moving the cursor over them, when stopped on error? You should previously check `If IsNumeric(string variable)`... `CDbl` works only if the text to be cast is a number.

Comment: That you assign a `CDbl` to a cell does not change its current format. If someone formatted that cell as Text it will remain as Text.

Comment: In reply to both responses, these worked fine before an update over the weekens. Also, the cells are formatted either as currency ( for the above code) and General in another file. No cells are set to "Text" format There are no errors in the code but these appear in the warnings flagged beside the cells on the worksheet.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot?